# How to return Cartesian of List elements

Tags: scala

I have List of 3 elements 1,2,3 :

```
  val s : List[String] = List("1" , "2" , "3")    //> s  : List[String] = List(1, 2, 3)

When I attempt to extract a cartesian of these elements : 
  s.map(m => m.map(m2 => (m,m2)))                 //> res0: List[scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(String, Char)]] = List(Vec
                                                  //| tor((1,1)), Vector((2,2)), Vector((3,3)))
```

Why is Cartesian product of list elements not being returned ?

Comment: Well... I do not understand what do you mean by Cartesian product. But If I am guessing right... then you want `s.map( m => s.map( m2 => (m, m2) ) )` which will give you - `List(List((1,1), (1,2), (1,3)), List((2,1), (2,2), (2,3)), List((3,1), (3,2), (3,3)))`.

Comment: Also note that there is a [`combination`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@combinations(n:Int):Iterator[Repr]) function which gives you all combinations of the collection with length `n`. In this case `s.combination(2)` will give you `List(List(1,2), List(1,3), List(2,3)` so if that's what you really want just use it!

Comment: By the way [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of just one `List` (or set in mathematics) does not make sense. What you want is Cartesian product of `s` with itself (in mathematical notation `S x S`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 s.map(m => m.map(m2 => (m,m2)))  
       ^ This is a String, which is being treated as a Seq[Char]

 s.map(m => m.map(m2 => (m,m2)))  
                  ^ This is a Char in the String, of which there is only one in each.
```

It's easier to see how this fails if the `String`s are longer.

```
scala> val s : List[String] = List("1a" , "2b" , "3c")
s: List[String] = List(1a, 2b, 3c)

scala> s.map(m => m.map(m2 => (m,m2))) 
res1: List[scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(String, Char)]] = List(Vector((1a,1), (1a,a)), Vector((2b,2), (2b,b)), Vector((3c,3), (3c,c)))
```

The inner `map` needs to use the same seed list:

```
scala> for(a <- s; b <- s) yield (a, b)
res7: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3))
```

Or:

```
scala> s.flatMap(a => s.map(b => (a, b)))
res8: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3))
```